# What is the relationship between pi and Feigenbaum's constant?

Tags: pi, elliptic-integrals

I am student who is new to bifurcation theory, and am interested in better understanding how Feigenbaum's constant relates to other constants.

This morning I divided pi (using math.pi in Python) by Feigenbaum's constant (to 30 decimal places; δ = 4.669201609102990671853203821578), which yielded 0.6728329416029073.

I found this number (rounded up to 6 decimal places) in a [chart of elliptic integrals](https://books.google.com/books?id=xFTsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=.672833&source=bl&ots=wl5N1_BKKU&sig=3ISicXZIuurx5bLb0JeRNmhCm6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5MWWkqHQAhVor1QKHacPBhgQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=.672833&f=false), but do not have enough understanding of bifurcation to draw a meaningful connection to the Heuman lambda function.

Is there any literature exploring period doubling and pi?

Comment: That is just a coincidence. The handbook that you link to contains many thousands of six-figure numbers, so it should be no great surprise that one of them matches $\pi/\delta$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks. That's what I figured. Are there resources you would recommend for better understanding π/δ?

Comment: As far as I know, $\pi$ has nothing to do with Feigenbaum's constant. If you have any reason to think otherwise, please share it with us.

Comment: My inquiry was born out of looking at this [graphic](http://inspirehep.net/record/1374528/plots) and wondering if there might be any interesting relationships between circumferences and diameters across the periods. I'm mostly trying to cultivate a stronger intuition about how the periods relate. In that regard, I found this thread helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577366/physical-intuition-for-period-doubling-bifurcations

Answer (score 3):

> *What is the relationship between π and [Feigenbaum's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) ? My inquiry was born 
>  out of looking at [this](http://inspirehep.net/record/1374528/plots) graphic.*

$\quad$ They are both related to shapes determined by [quadratic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form). Thus, the value of 
 the former is given by $~\dfrac\pi8=\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}~dx,~$ and that of the latter by the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) $x_{n+1}=r~x_n(1-x_n).~$ Notice any similarities there ? ;-$)$ Also, looking at the graphic, one 
 cannot help but notice that the periods in question resemble a [parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola), which is hardly 
 surprising, since the recursive expression of $\{x\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is parabolic, and, as we all know, circles 
 and ellipses, as well as parabolas, are ultimately [conic sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). But this should not by any 
 means be misconstrued by thinking that their numerical values are supposedly connected. 
 Thus, Euler's famous constant *e* is also related to the other conic section, the [hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola), 
 since $~\displaystyle\int_1^e\dfrac1x~dx=1,~$ but no one actually expects them to be **numerically** related. $($Hope 
 this helps$).$

Comment: What a great response. Thank you!